# Adding toast on FirebaseRecylerView Adapter specifically on "onBindViewHolder"

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview, android-adapter, firebaseui

I have a problem displaying toast on an `RecylerViewAdapter` with firebase.  I was gonna use it on an image button which is delete as you can see below the `onBindViewHolder`.  But the problem is, `getContext` doesn't work

```
public class AddClassAdapter extends FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<AddClass, AddClassAdapter.myViewHolder>{ 

  /**
   * Initialize a {@link RecyclerView.Adapter} that listens to a Firebase query. See
   * {@link FirebaseRecyclerOptions} for configuration options.
   *
   * @param options
   */
  private OnItemClickListener listener, listener1;
  public AddClassAdapter(@NonNull FirebaseRecyclerOptions<AddClass> options) {
      super(options);
  }

  @Override
  protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull myViewHolder holder, int position, @NonNull AddClass model) {
      holder.className.setText(model.getClassName);  

      holder.deleteBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
          @Override
          public void onClick(View view) {
              Toast.makeText(, "Course Added Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
          }
      });
  }
```

I've tried `getContext()` but it gives me an error, also, I tried using these in the main activity:

```
Context context = getApplicationContext();
AddClassAdapter adapter = new AddClassAdapater(context);
```

But it won't work and gives an error of

> Required type:FirebaseRecyclerOptions <com.example.attendancechecker_application.AddClass>

Is there a way to have a toast in the RecyclerViewAdapter?

Comment: Oh a big thanks for that link! just used view.getContext()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You instantiate the Adapter from your **Activity** class, there you have the **Context** Object - you can pass it in the Constructor of your Adapter Class and use it here for whatever you want.

The error you get

> Required type:FirebaseRecyclerOptions
> <com.example.attendancechecker_application.AddClass>

is because, you did not properly declare the constructor of your Adapter to accept the an Argument of Type **FirebaseRecyclerOptions** and an Argument of type **Context**.

**This should do the work:**

```java
public class AddClassAdapter extends FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<AddClass, AddClassAdapter.myViewHolder>{ 

  private final Context context;
  private OnItemClickListener listener, listener1;

  public AddClassAdapter(@NonNull FirebaseRecyclerOptions<AddClass> options, Context context) {
      super(options);
      this.context = context;
  }

  @Override
  protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull myViewHolder holder, int position, @NonNull AddClass model) {
      holder.className.setText(model.getClassName);  

      holder.deleteBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
          @Override
          public void onClick(View view) {
              Toast.makeText(context, "Course Added Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
          }
      });
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, hopefully can use that one, but for now I solved the problem by just adding view.getContext() after toast.maketext(.